# C# Xaml Winrt/Universal App determine if mobile device

Tags: c#, xaml, mobile, windows-runtime, smaato

Okay so here's the deal I have a windows 8.1 Store app (WINRT) does not currently support Windows Phone(Maybe for windows 10) In any case I have advertisements setup, which work. But I have SMAATO complaining I'm sending too many requests that are from non-mobile devices (pretty much everything) How can they tell it's from a non-mobile device? In any case I'd like to catch this before hand and if it seems like SMAATO won't provide an add then to use a different provider. (Unfortunately at the moment the only one who whole heartedly supports WinRT/Universal APP advertisements is Microsoft's PubCenter, and Adduplex., If someone can recommend another I'll give it a try.)